# Many readers and one writer on a regular file on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

What guarantees are made on Linux (or on Unix derivatives, in general) regarding concurrently accessing a regular file with many readers and one writer?

In particular, I have one writer writing to the *end* of a file and many readers trying to read from that file until the writer indicates (through some other means) that it is done writing (i.e., the readers ignore EOF). Is this ok?

I am aware of a few other similar questions on the SE network, but none give a clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each reader will be it's own process.  During it's read loop, it will read the latest amount of data since the last time it read the file... assuming it keeps the file handle open.  This will be independent of other readers.  I'm not sure what you mean by "guarantees", but as long as the file handle(s) remain valid, all readers will get the data.

It will also be independent of the writer.

For an example, give this a try... open several terminal sessions and in each one run "tail -F /var/log/audit.log"  Then trigger some event that would cause an audit entry... ie. open a new ssh session to the server, for example.

You will see all of the tail -F's display the change in the file.  Many readers (tail) and one writer (rsyslogd).